# How to play one audio file at a time in a series of audio files in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have several audio files to be played, so I used `ListView` to represent every audio file as an item of `ListView`, each one with its own controllers (play/pause button and duration slider). The code is as follows (I have used one audio file for all of the items for simplicity sake):

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class AudioTestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AudioTestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Songs")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => const AudioItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AudioItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AudioItem> createState() => _AudioItemState();
}

class _AudioItemState extends State<AudioItem> {
  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;

  Duration duration = Duration.zero;  // For total duration
  Duration position = Duration.zero;  // For the current position

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setAudioPlayer();

    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        duration = newDuration;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          position = newPosition;
        });
      }
    });

    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          isPlaying = state == PlayerState.playing;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> setAudioPlayer() async {
    final player = AudioCache(prefix: "assets/audios/");
    final url = await player.load("song.mp3");
    audioPlayer.setSourceUrl(url.path);
    audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.stop);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFFF4F2FF),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: position.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
            max: duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                position = Duration(milliseconds: value.toInt());
              });
              audioPlayer.seek(position);
            },
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              isPlaying
                  ? await audioPlayer.pause()
                  : await audioPlayer.resume();
            },
            child: CircleAvatar(
              child: Icon(isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image]

Now when I play a music file, and later tap on another item to play it, both of them plays at the same time, but I want the previous one to pause and only the current one to play.
How can I achieve this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just make one `AudioPlayer` and your logic will be far easier

Comment: one AudioPlayer wouldn't work, because then there will be one AudioPlayer reference for all the items, so all of them will listen to this one AudioPlayer which makes the behavior even worse.

Comment: so use an int active index and show slider only for active item - for example if you click play button on 3rd item set the index to 2, call setState and your list will be rebuilt

Comment: can you please write your suggested implementation as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

create the audio player in the parent class and pass it to the children. Then before you play stop the player and then play it with new url

```
widget.player.stop()
```

Use this to stop the player

**EDIT**

```dart
class AudioItem extends StatefulWidget {
final AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
final int currentIndex;
final int index;
final VoidCallback setIndex;
  const AudioItem({Key? key, required this.audioPlayer, required required this.currentIndex, required this.index, required this.setIndex}) : super(key: key);
```

Add these 3 variables to the Audio item. When you add these Widgets in the tree pass the values

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Songs")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => const AudioItem(
         audioPlayer: audioPlayer,
         currentIndex:currentIndex, <--this is the variable in which we know which item is playing. 
         index: index,
         setIndex: (){
          currentIndex = index;
          setState((){});
         }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now when the play button is clicked call this setIndex method that will update the parent.

Comment: one AudioPlayer wouldn't work, because then there will be one AudioPlayer reference for all the items, so all of them will listen to this one AudioPlayer which makes the behavior even worse.

Comment: Pass 3 values. 1. Audio player, 2. Index of each item, 3 current player index. Now in the listener check if current index is same as the item index and update only that specific item

Comment: can you please post your solution, because I am trying to implement your suggestion, but I haven't been able to.